# LedAds advertising script: stats not updating properly, all stuck at 1 impression

Tags: php, mysql

I installed the old LedAds php scripts (http://www.ledscripts.com/) to run a simple ad rotator on my sites and they work really nicely. I sorted out a code issue which stopped me being able to log in to them, thanks to a Google search... but this one I can't find.

The ads show. The clicks work. The rotator does its random thing. Everything works great.

But behind the scenes, the stats show 1 impression or click for each ad, no more. If there's a click, there's no impression. If there's an impression, there's no click.

Database contains pla_ads (aid, type, did, active, datetime), pla_images (with image URLs, link URLs, alt text, sizes), pla_richtext (for ad html that doesn't fit the nice, simple image+URL format) and pla_impressions (aid, impdate, displays, clicks). The last is obviously the one that should be growing.

The table is built when the script installs:

CREATE TABLE {prefix}_impressions (
  aid int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  impdate date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  displays bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  clicks int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (aid,impdate)
) TYPE=MyISAM;

The php that does the business is here (saved as text for simplicity): http://www.oddjotter.com/ad_class.txt

I manually edited a value in the impressions table to make one ad's impression old (previous day). After a few site visits, I hit that ad - and it now says 2 impressions in the stats but won't count any further impressions for today.

If someone can see why the code's only recording one hit (or click) a day, I'd be most grateful!

Comment: Ahaha, figured it out. My brain kept twitching where the update sql is generated: it's the now() function that causes the trouble. Changed it to date(now()) and it works like a dream (so far). Sorted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this expression: **where (impdate = now()) and (aid = $key)**. It's the now() function that causes the trouble. Changed it to **date(now())** (there are two or three occurrences) and it works fine.